# Is it possible to rename a joined column during an inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have two tables, `owner` and `dog`. Both have column `name`, but I'd like to join them, so there is a problem since both tables have column `name`. Can I rename (alias) the `name` column in the dog table during the query?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
select d.Name as DogName, o.Name
from Dog d
inner join Owner o on d.OwnerID = o.OwnerID
```

Comment: How does `Owner o` (third line) differs from `Owner as o`?

Comment: @FRD It's just an abbreviated way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @RedFilter is there a way to do this in oracle without a subquery ? I’d prefer something like your solution here.

Comment: I'm embarrassed on how simple it is lol

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can, but then you must list out all of the fields instead of using `select *`:

```
    select o.*, d.*
      from owner o
inner join (select dog_id, name as dog_name, breed, age, owner_id from dog) d
    on o.owner_id = d.owner_id
```

Comment: But, then, you should be using Select * anyway, so that's not really a loss.

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb. Would joining like make a difference on what indexes are used on the joined table?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible and very simple, do your SQL normally and add a comma after the asterisk and use 'AS'.

Before:

> SELECT * FROM owner
>
> INNER JOIN dog
>
> ON owner.id = dog.id

After:

> SELECT *, dog.name AS dogName FROM owner
>
> INNER JOIN dog
>
> ON owner.id = dog.id

Answer (score 1):

```
Agents.lastname as AgentName


Where,
Agents = Table Name
lastname = Column Name in table
AgentName = New Column name that you want to add
```

Example:

```
SELECT 
    Buyers.id, 
    Buyers.mobile,
    Agents.lastname as AgentName
FROM Buyers 
INNER JOIN Agents ON Buyers.agentId=Agents.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rename the columns in the output of a join, that is called an alias. However, the fact that they are the same does not cause any problem; they just need to be fully qualified.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Give any Alias name to the column but there is some rules like the alias name must not the key word of the SQL Server, it must not contain space, if you want space then it should be in [] you can not use some symbols for alias.

Ex :-
Select owner.Id As [Int], Owner.*,dog.*
From Owner inner join Gog On Owner.Id = Dog.Id